# Create dynamic variable name bash and get value

Tags: bash

I have a function in bash that get param a string, for example:

`MYSQL_DATABASE` then I want in my file to create a var named `VAR_MYSQL_DATABASE` but I can`t get the value.

```
create_var()
{

    read -p "Enter $1 : " VAR_$1
    printf VAR_$1 // print VAR_MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME instead what I typed, so how do I get the value?
    if [[ -z VAR_$1 ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "No input entered. Enter $1"
        create_entry $1
    fi  
}

create_var "MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME"
```

Comment: So I am asking from user `MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME` and set a variable in the bash script with the name. The idea is that I have to ask 15 variables and because of this I made this function to be dry. If I use this line `read -p "Enter MYSQL_USER_NAME : " MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME` all works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`declare`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare) built-in in `bash`,

```
name="MYSQL_DATABASE"
declare VAR_${name}="Some junk string"
printf "%s\n" "${VAR_MYSQL_DATABASE}"
Some junk string
```

With the above logic, you can modify how your `name` variable is controlled, either present locally. If it is passed as argument from a function/command-line do

```
declare VAR_${1}="Your string value here"
```

---

Perhaps you want to achieve something like this,

```
create_var()
{
    read -p "Enter value: " value
    declare -g VAR_$1="$value"

    dynamVar="VAR_$1"

    if [[ -z "${!dynamVar}" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "No input entered. Enter $1"
        create_entry $1
    fi
}
```

So, here we are creating the dynamic variable using the `declare` built-in and with the dynamic part `VAR_$1` cannot be referenced directly as normal variables, hence using indirect expansion `{!variable}` to see if the created variable is available.

Comment: Good answer ++, you may add that only allowed characters in a Unix variable name should be passed in `$1`

Comment: Sorry, I think I was confusing with the first piece of code, I edited the question.

Comment: you can't pass the variable and read from user at same time. Please state your requirments clearly

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks for the feedback really appreciate it!

Comment: If I do this `read -p "Enter MYSQL_USER_NAME : " MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME` all works, but I want to wrap this in a function and call it with the string param `MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME`.

Comment: If you `declare VAR_${1}` how do you call it in same function? Dynamically?

Comment: Yes this solves my problem. So when you said `you can't pass the variable and read from user at same time` was a missunderstand?

Comment: @IonVasile: I thought you were using `$1` as argument and the value for read. I stand corrected,

Comment: `declare` makes the variable local to the function, unless you use the `-g` option. If it's local to the function, there's no real need for it to have any specific name.

Comment: Yes I camed back for -g :)

Comment: @IonVasile : Updated!

Comment: i couldn't find documentation related to `-g`. Can anyone link me about this options.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

create_var() {
        declare -g VAR_$1
        ref=VAR_$1
        read -p "Enter $1: " "VAR_$1"

        echo "inside : ${!ref}"
}

create_var "MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME"
echo "output : $VAR_MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME"
```

`declare -g` will make sure the variable exists outside of the function scope, and `"VAR_$1"` is used to dynamically create the variable names.

Output :

```
Enter MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME: Apple
inside : Apple
output : Apple
```

Comment: The only thing is that `echo "inside : $VAR_MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME"` is not dynamic. `MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME` is a param. So somehow I should use `echo "inside : $VAR_$1"`

Comment: Yes, I know. This was just for example sake. It is actually dynamic. I'll edit my example.

Comment: @IonVasile added the example using indirection to get the value from the dynamic variable.

Comment: `declare -g` would be preferable to `export` in versions of `bash` that support it.

Comment: `read -p "Enter $1: " "VAR_$1"` is sufficient; there is no need for a command substitution here.

Comment: @chepner you're right, I was overcomplicating the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `printf` function with the `-v` option to "print" to a variable name.

```
create_var()
{
    while : ; do
        IFS= read -r -p "Enter $1 : " value
        if [[ -n $value ]]; then
            printf -v "VAR_$1" '%s' "$value"
            return
        fi
        printf 'No input entered. Enter %s\n' "$1"
    done  
}
```

(I've rewritten your function with a loop to avoid what appeared to be an attempt at recursion.)