# How to reference bash variables depending on a value of a second variable (dynamic variable usage)?

Tags: bash, shell

I am kind of stuck on this one.

I have three preset variables declared in my config file defaults.cfg:

```
ANDROID_4.4=android-4.4.4_r1
ANDROID_6.0=android-6.0.1_r79
ANDROID_7.0=android-7.1.1_r28
```

Each of these variables contains the preferred branch-name for building a specified Android Version.
How do i access the value of those depending on the value of ANDROID_VERSION.

Example how i tried it:

```
#!/bin/bash    
source defaults.cfg   
ANDROID-VERSION=4.4
`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b ${ANDROID_{$ANDROID_VERSION}}`
```

I can not override that indirect value because, this should work on jenkins, and jenkins only gets 4.4, 6.0, 7.0 and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not even close to my problem

Comment: It is about dynamically accessing it, the context might be different, but the tool is the same

Comment: Use the `declare` built in with indirect expansion

Comment: as i understand the author uses a config file and wants to read that config to declare variables from it. My config file is basically a bash script on its on and gets bound to the main script by using source config

Comment: Also look up this answer too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437044/create-dynamic-variable-name-bash-and-get-value/42437143#42437143

Comment: `ANDROID_4.4` cannot be a unix variable name due to presence of DOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to config file to get the value as per the version:

```
ANDROID_VERSION='4.4'
awk -F= -v ver="$ANDROID_VERSION" '$1=="ANDROID_" ver { print $2 }' config.file

android-4.4.4_r1
```

If you want to pass it to your command then use:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b \
$(awk -F= -v ver="$ANDROID_VERSION" '$1=="ANDROID_" ver { print $2 }' config.file)
```

Comment: That looks more like it, i will give it a shot and report back afterwards

Comment: Not yet. Hope i get to it later this day

Comment: Not quite what i was looking for, but it is actually a much neater way to to what i want to do, thank you for your solution