# Bash variable of variable and assign to a variable

Tags: bash

I have a scenario as follows:

```
testing1=acs
testing2=rcs
testing3=mes
testing4=gcp
```

i need to print the values: acs rcs mes gcp
I am using following for loop:

```
 TotalOutputString=''
 for current_number in {1..${max_number}}
 do
    TotalOutputString="${TotalOutputString}  ${testing$current_number} "
 done

 echo $TotalOutputString
```

But this is not giving proper output. Its only printing numbers.

Comment: Why don't you use an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create dynamic variable name bash and get value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437044/create-dynamic-variable-name-bash-and-get-value), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222487)

Comment: You shouldn't be getting any numbers; this is a syntax error in `bash`. (You also aren't iterating over the numbers 1 through 4 if you are using `bash`, but rather iterating once with `current_number` set to the literal string `{1..4}`.)

Comment: You should use arrays instead of this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `${!key)` to indirectly access the variable specified by `key`.  In your case:

```
TotalOutputString=''
for((i=1; 1<=$max_number; i++)) {
    key="testing$current_number"
    TotalOutputString="${TotalOutputString}  ${!key} "
}
echo $TotalOutputString
```